# Restore default USB WiFi packages

Tags: wireless, kubuntu

My problem and solution are (seemingly) really simple: Everything was working great on my Kubuntu 19.04 install, then I installed/uninstalled a few things (mostly related to MariaDB and Skype password storage issues, which led me to remove AppArmor, keyring, and other things I don't even understand) and now my USB WiFi is not getting detected anymore.

I wouldn't have posted here, but I for the life of me can't figure out what that original package was that I removed. Is there a way to install/activate the default packages/modules for USB WiFi?

**== Edit: Adding diagnostic info as requested in comments ===**

```
root@bandook:~# nmcli device
DEVICE   TYPE      STATE        CONNECTION 
wlp6s0   wifi      connected    Bhokali    
enp7s0   ethernet  unavailable  --         
docker0  bridge    unmanaged    --         
lo       loopback  unmanaged    --  

root@bandook:~# lshw -C network | grep -i "Wireless interface" -A12 -B1
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: BCM43142 802.11b/g/n
       vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
       logical name: wlp6s0
       version: 01
       serial: 9c:d2:1e:e5:47:33
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.30.223.271 (r587334) ip=192.168.1.7 latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:18 memory:f7900000-f7907fff

root@bandook:~# lspci -knn | grep -A4 -i "Network controller"
06:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
        Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1704 802.11n + BT 4.0 [1028:0016]
        Kernel driver in use: wl
        Kernel modules: bcma, wl
07:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 0c)

root@bandook:~# cat /var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.state
[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

root@bandook:~# networkctl status
WARNING: systemd-networkd is not running, output will be incomplete.

●        State: n/a
       Address: 192.168.1.7 on wlp6s0
                172.17.0.1 on docker0
                fe80::7ebf:af75:5b36:6c94 on wlp6s0
       Gateway: 192.168.1.1 (Binatone Telecommunication Pvt. Ltd) on wlp6s0
                fe80::ed2:b5ff:fe82:9fab (Binatone Telecommunication Pvt. Ltd) on wlp6s0

root@bandook:~# lsusb
Bus 001 Device 029: ID 0a5c:21d7 Broadcom Corp. BCM43142 Bluetooth 4.0
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:5756 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 024: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

root@bandook:~# rfkill
ID TYPE      DEVICE        SOFT      HARD
 0 wlan      phy0     unblocked unblocked
 1 wlan      brcmwl-0 unblocked unblocked
 4 bluetooth hci0     unblocked unblocked
```

Comment: If you don't want to do a clean re-install, try poking around in */var/log/apt/history.log* or earlier to identify what all you deleted, intentionally or otherwise. And there's no harm in asking here ;)

Comment: @DKBose Hmmm, thanks but that doesn't seem to help. There are too many entries there, and even checking all the `apt purge` entries doesn't seem to help. :( I guess I'll take the investigative route and try to find the relevant drivers for my card.  By the way, `lshw` says the following, so which drivers should I install?

`product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.`

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea about drivers!

Comment: Please edit your question and post the output of the commands: 1. `nmcli device` 2. `sudo lshw -C network | grep -i "Wireless interface" -A12 -B1`  3 `lspci -knn | grep -A4 -i "Network controller"`  4. `cat /var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.state` 5. `lsusb` 6. `rfkill` and 7. `networkctl status`

Comment: @Marmayogi Thanks for your assistance! :-) I've added the info to my question. However, most of the outputs don't detect/list my USB WiFi device, which is a Leoxsys (Realtek) device.

Comment: @Marmayogi Also, on that note, would you be able to advise me on which company's wireless cards are best supported on Linux? Mine inbuilt one is Broadcomm, which I gather is one of the worst choices on Linux! :P

Comment: Command `lshw` did not display the presence of USB WiFi dongle. I was looking for `lsusb` and `rfkill` commands output but you missed to post them! If you plug in USB WiFi dongle, then dongle may emit LED glow. Did you observe any such glow? Your broadcom Wi-Fi is detected and driver is loaded too. The broadcom device is `wlp6s0`  which is connected with hotspot/broadband device `Bhokali`. Your IP is `192.168.1.7` and Gateway IP `192.168.1.1`. Did you attempt to connect broadcom WiFi to internet? What was the result? BTW, is your computer laptop? Thanks.

Comment: @Marmayogi Sorry! I added those two also at the end of my question. No, no lights blink when I connect the USB WiFi. Earlier they used to blink and it used to work. The Broadcomm one is the built-in wireless card and works okay (but not that great). Yes, I have a laptop, and yes, the Broadcomm (on-board) connects to the Internet just fine. It's the USB Realtek one what used to work but doesn't anymore.

Comment: @dotslash, Do you have more specs regarding your USB Realtek Wi-Fi card such as model, version,  etc.? Let us find out correct drivers and install them!

Comment: @Marmayogi If it helps, the product name is "Leoxsys LEO-NANO150N Wireless N 11N Wi-Fi Nano USB Adapter Dongle". Don't know how to get more specs, sorry. :(

Comment: I attempted to download latest driver for LEO-NANO150N from [official website](https://www.leoxsys.com/downloads.php) but it throws `network problems`. I tried many times, same result. The `chipset` of your USB Wi-Fi dongle should be known before trying dirvers from other web-sites. Did you plug-in USB Wi-Fi dongle before you ran `lsusb` command?

Comment: @Marmayogi Yes, the dongle is always connected, and was connected when I shared the output. Are there any other ways to detect/query the chipset? Maybe I should write to the company. :D

Comment: This [website](https://freekaamaal.com/deals/leoxsys-802-11n-mini-wireless-n-11n-wi-fi-nano-usb-wi-fi-adapter-dongle-wifi-at-rs-349) recommends `Original REALTEK 8188ETV ` Chipset for stable and higher performance. I am trying to gather more details in this regard in order to make sure this information is accurate.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93714/discussion-between-marmayogi-and-dotslash).